# Unity Build installs but leads to a black screen

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, build-error

I'm pretty new in this world and I'm trying to build and run my first Unity project in my Android device but I can't.

The APP is installed correctly but when I try to open it, it pops the screen that says "Made with Unity" and then leads to a black screen where nothing happens and my game doesn't work.

I've used the Android SDK tools for Windows which I have downloaded here[1](https://developer.android.com/studio).

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What type is type is the build destination, what have you used in terms of packages, what happens if you make a blank new project and compile it up

Comment: @BugFinder I've already edited the post. And i've tried to open a new blank project and its works

Comment: So its something you've "done" which means you can narrow it down, did you add your scenes?

Comment: @BugFinder Yes, I've added all the scenes which include the main menu and all 10 levels

Comment: have you used anything like hdrp, databases, what do you do on start up.. you would need to narrow it down theres nothing youve shown here that we can use to help you.

Comment: @BugFinder No, I just made a videogame using basic tutorials and stuff, and i firstly tried to Build my project with this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pNLJsKUAf4c. Also I've tried to understand this post  https://answers.unity.com/questions/1097721/android-apk-build-can-install-but-wont-start-1.html and i had actually opened the Logcat but i didnt really undertand what those messages mean.

Comment: Post the messages from logcat, look for the words error, failed etc.. those are the ones you need to worry about the most

Comment: @BugFinder and then what should i do with those messages?

Comment: well either fix them or post them - no one on SO can see them as it is and so there is nothing anyone can help you with

Comment: @BugFinder alright, I'm gonna try what you said, anyway thanks for your time bro I really appreciate it :D

Comment: .... so not male...

Answer (score -2):

This question doesn't help, because there are bajillion ways a Unity build can end up in a blank screen.

So, for the sake of making most of it with so little context, try to do the following steps:

1) Verify the build order is correct: Place always first the scene where your camera is. And try to place the scenes in a way that makes sense in the structure of your game (ex : MainScene - > MenuScene -> GameScene -> LevelScene)

2) Search for errors in build. Probably the most helpful advice i can give. Check the log in your output_log.txt in the build folder as mentioned in this thread: https://answers.unity.com/questions/125049/is-there-any-way-to-view-the-console-in-a-build.html